# Реверс массива С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Покажите пожалуйста как это сделать красиво используя стандартный массив, очень смущает `int *_arr = new int[len];` <- вообще честно говоря жутковатый синтаксис, объясните его пожалуйста, почему нельзя просто написать  `int _arr[len];`

Почему место `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) _arr[i] = arr[i];` я не могу просто передать копию `_arr = arr` ?

```
include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void reversed(int *arr, int len);

int main() {

    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    reversed(arr, 9);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) cout << arr[i];



    getchar();
}
void reversed(int *arr, int len) {

    int *_arr = new int[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) _arr[i] = arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = _arr[(len - 1) - i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я больше в обучающих целях, так бы я, наверно, использовал бы  std::list<int>, а там все есть.

Comment: "Почему место for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) _arr[i] = arr[i]; я не могу просто передать копию arr[i] ?" - вопрос не ясен. Что за "копия arr[i]"?

Comment: Простите, поправил.    _arr = копия(arr)

Comment: @Oleksii: В языках С и С++ "голые" массивы являются *некопируемыми* объектами. Поэтому "передать копию" голого массива в С/С++ невозможно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> почему нельзя просто написать  int _arr[len];

В языке С++ размеры в объявлениях массивов должны быть Целочисленными Константными Выражениями, т.е. попросту выражаясь целыми *константами времени компиляции*. В вашем случае `len` не является константой времени компиляции. Это означает, что объявить массив `int _arr[len]` вы не сможете. Создать массив размера `len` в С++ можно только через динамическое выделение памяти, либо явно (напр. через `new[]`), либо неявно (напр. через `std::vector`).

Однако задача реверса массива запросто решается in-place, без заведения дополнительного массива-копии. Поэтому метод создания дополнительного массива к данной теме не должен иметь никакого отношения вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Есть стандартный алгоритм `std::reverse` (как [учит нас Sean Parent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH6sSOr-yk8), желательно по-максимуму пользоваться стандартными алгоритмами вместо циклов). Кроме того, в C++11 добавлены `std::begin` и `std::end`, которые понимают, кроме прочего, и массивы с их размерами. В таком случае ваш пример можно реализовать таким образом:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    for (auto i : arr)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

[Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85ba3adcba115bb5).

Answer (score 0):

```
@AnT Спасибо за наводку.
```

Так можно делать без копии массива:

```
void reversed(int *arr, int len) {

        for (int i = 0, j = len - 1; i<j; i++, j--){

            arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[i] - arr[j];
            arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[j];
        }


    }
```

Comment: Не занимайтесь бессмысленными извращениями. Обмен двух значений делается при помощи третьей переменной: `int t = arr[i]; arr[i] = arr[j]; arr[j] = t;` или, лучше, при помощи `std::swap`.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к AnT. Постороннему без бутылки водки невозможно понять что здесь происходит. Если какой-то код вам кажется замысловатым, то для другого человека он станет неразрешимой головоломкой

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/rT4Kj9 разницы всё равно нету) хороший компилятор и так поймёт вас.